# Running tasks from an included gradle build in order

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle composite build project, which runs tasks from an [included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). I am not able to make changes to the included build.

For a certain task, I want to first clean the included build and then build it. I.e., I want to do (loosely):

```
some-project:clean
some-project:build
```

where `some-project` is the included build. I tried doing this by setting up tasks which depend on those external tasks:

```
task cleanIncludedBuild {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild("some-project").task("clean")
}

task buildIncludedBuild {
    dependsOn cleanIncludedBuild
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild("some-project").task("build")
}
```

However, since there is no ordering between dependencies, this execution order is valid as declared:

```
some-project:build
some-project:clean
cleanIncludedBuild
buildIncludedBuild
```

Though this is of course not what I'm after.

I thought of doing something like

```
gradle.includedBuild("some-project").task("build").dependsOn cleanIncludedBuild
```

but the value returned by `task()` above is of type `IncludedBuildTaskReference`, which essentially are read-only references to the underlying task, and do not allow adding dependencies.

Comment: I guess this is not possible, maybe you should write about this in the Gradle forums or in the issue tracker, so it can be considered for the future. Maybe to improve you could make `clean->otherclean`, `build->otherbuild`, `build.shouldRunAfter clean` and `cleanBuild->clean, build`. I guess it could still happen that build is run before clean, but maybe you can increase probability at least.

Comment: Or you actually **do** modify the included build, but without changing its files. You can at any time use an initialization script, e. g. in `~/.gradle/init.d/` or via `-i` and there do something like `if (rootProject.name == 'whatever') build.dependsOn clean`. This is only pseudo-code of course, the real code would be a few more lines.